# How Can I Encrypt and Decrypt Soap XML Messages?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, encryption, fiddler

I want to know how to encrypt a soap message and send it to the server that the server can decrypt, process the message, encrypt the response again and send it back to the client... How can I do that? My point is to hide messages from web debuggers like fiddler. I searched and found the named SoapExtension but I really couldn't find the proper example for this.

1. How can I implement this encryption and decryption to web methods?
2. I am using HttpWebRequest to request so my requests are manual. I need to learn to decrypt and encrypt messages in clients manually not with service references.

Comment: 3. Nobody is going to do the work for unless you hire somebody. SO is not a freelance board. You gotta do the work yourself and seriously if you are that advanced already sending network traffic back and forth then choosing an encryption method and just programming the algorithm shouldn't be much of a challenge. I mean really, you can come up with just a simple Caesar cipher to begin with, and then expand further once you got this working

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly note that SO is not a code writing service so I'm voting for closure, sorry.

Comment: @Tomek I just want to see skeleton not all code. like what should I do with web config file to activate encrypt and decrypt

Comment: @dreamerx then your question should be rephrased and explain what you have done so far, your setup etc Like do you use ASP.NET or you wrote a C# console app using websockets etc.?. and what research you have done and what you have actually tried and got stuck with, right now how the question stands it does not show much of initiative.

Comment: This could be satisfied with Message Encryption.  This is the sort of thing WCF is great at doing without you having to write volumes of code.  Doing it manually is going to be a pain and will likely lead to gaps, since it is easy to "forget" to encrypt a header, query parameter, or other unsecured flow.  I do separately question the intent - if you are trying to block Fiddler and other MITM proxies, do your own certificate validation.

Comment: @Mitch  if I have ssl certificate web service will it encrypt this messages automatically?

Comment: @Tomek I will do it

Comment: @dreamerx, yes.  SSL would encrypt the messages in flight, protecting them from normal passive monitoring.  Tools like Fiddler do have an option to "pretend" to be your server, but they cannot fake your SSL certificate.  If you check for your SSL certificate (thumbprint, serial number + CA, or some other means of verification), then Fiddler cannot fool your code into sending data.  See https://jarrettmeyer.com/2017/10/19/validating-remote-server-certificates for an example with `HttpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`.